# Can't change desktop resolution - "Size 1920x1080 not found in available modes"

Tags: display-resolution

My xrandr gives

```
 xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1360 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00 +
   1360x768      59.96*   59.80  
   1152x864      60.00  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   680x384       59.96    59.80  
   640x480       59.94  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       72.19  
   320x240       60.05  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

If I try

```
xrandr -s 1920x1080
Size 1920x1080 not found in available modes
```

Also I tried

```
 cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

But new problems occur

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  29
```

How to add this one to available modes? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: `xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1920x1080`

Answer (score 8):

This is what I found in the Ubuntu wiki:

## Adding undetected resolutions

Due to buggy hardware or drivers, your monitor's correct resolutions may not always be detected. For example, the EDID data block queried from your monitor may be incorrect.

If the mode already exists, but just isn't associated for the particular output, you can add it like this:

`xrandr --addmode S-video 800x600`

If the mode doesn't yet exist, you'll need to create it first by specifying a modeline:

``` xrandr --newmode <Mode``Line> ```

You may create a modeline using the gtf or cvt utility. For example, if you want to add a mode with resolution 800x600 at 60 Hz, you can enter the following command: (The output is shown following.)

`cvt 800 600 60`

```
`800x600 59.86 Hz (CVT 0.48M3) hsync: 37.35 kHz; pclk: 38.25 MHz
 Modeline "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -
 hsync +vsync`
```

Then copy the information after the word "Modeline" into the xrandr command:

`xrandr --newmode "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync`

After the mode is entered, it needs to be added to the output using the `--addmode` command as explained above.

---

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

---

Comment: Take llok at my edit please!

Comment: You have to use --addmode if it's not already available.Its the last sentence in my answer